# If function $f + g$ is bounded, does it imply that $f$ and $g$ are bounded?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I know that if $f$ and $g$ are bounded, then $f + g$ is bounded. However, is the converse true?

Proof:

Since $f+g$ is bounded, then that means $|f(x) + g(x)| \leq M$ for some positive constant $M$ and $\forall x$. By triangle inequality, $|f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)|$. However, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ are not bounded, but sum up to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter example: any unbounded function plus it's negative (also unbounded) will sum to the zero function which is bounded